# How to declare a new function in namespace App\Controller?

Tags: php, function, symfony, namespaces, declaration

I wrote those lines of code that convert a birthday date to an age.

I am gonna use this code in many controllers and in many route functions!
So I decided to place it in a function and I call `calculate_age()`.

My question is how can I declare that function or any function  **once** inside the `namespace App\Controller;`? So I can use it in all the controllers.

Function code :

```
public function calculate_age($birthday): ?int
{
    $current_date = date('d-m-Y', time());
    $info         = explode(' ', $birthday);
    $months       = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
    $numbers      = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12'];
    $i            = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 11; ++$i) {
        if ($info[2] == $months[$i]) {
            $info[2] = $numbers[$i];
        }
    }
    $all = $info[1].'-'.$info[2].'-'.$info[3];

    $difference = date_diff(date_create($current_date), date_create($all));
    $age        = \intval($difference->format('%y'));

    return $age;
}
```

Comment: As far as I know you cannot. You better make a model name Age_Calculator and make a public static mehtod like this in that model.

public static calculate_age($birthday){
Your code goes here
}

And call it in your controller using the model and method name
\App\Age_Calculator::calculate_age($given_date);

Comment: or you can make a trait. but I prefer this model system

Comment: What do u mean by make a model ? what are the models ? (never heared of them) and how to make one?

Comment: Sorry if I misjudge. Are not you using laravel? The solve is for Laravel

Comment: Nope , i am using Symfony 4.4

Comment: Why not use a service for this? That's the best place to share reusable code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally, since it's a function that calculates age, you would have a Person model and would put this function there, then you would call it on your people controller, it would be something like(this is a generic code, ok?):

`$age = $this->Person->calculate_age($birthday);`

Another option (but I don't recommend) is to have this function in the main model, so it can be accessed from all the class models that inherit from it.

Alternatively(but also not recommended for this case), you could have a generic static service class so you could put functions that that are more generic and don't belong to a specific model, some kind of helper then you could just do:

`$age = YourHelperClass::calculate_age($birthday);`

If you don't know how models work, I suggest you search about MVC, but basically, a model will contain all the methods related to the logic of your app and the controller should just control the flow of the logic.
Models should be thick and controllers should be thin.

Comment: Yes I add the function to the user.php entity file and it works ! thanks